# select rows where related record doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve rows from a mysql database as follows: I have a contract table, a contract line item table, and another table called udac.  I need all contracts which DO NOT have a line item record with criteria based on a relationship between contract line item and udac. If there is a better way to state this question, let me know.

Table Structures

```
----contract---------------------     ---contractlineitem-----------
| id | customer_id | entry_date |     | id | contract_id | udac_id |
---------------------------------     ------------------------------
| 1  | 1234        | 2010-01-01 |     | 1  | 1           | 5       |
| 2  | 2345        | 2016-01-31 |     | 2  | 1           | 2       |
---------------------------------     | 3  | 1           | 1       |
                                      | 4  | 2           | 4       |
                                      | 5  | 2           | 2       |
                                      ------------------------------

---udac----------
| id | udaccode |
-----------------
| 1  |  SWBL/R  |
| 2  |  SWBL    |
| 3  |  ABL/R   |
| 4  |  ABL     |
| 5  |  XRS/F   |
-----------------
```

Given the above data, contract 2 would show up but contract 1 would not, because it has contractlineitems that point to udacs that end in /F or /R.

Here's what i have so far, but it's not correct.

```
SELECT   c.*
  FROM   contract c
  JOIN   contractlineitem cli
    ON   c.id = cli.contract_id
 WHERE   c.entry_timestamp > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
   AND   NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT   cli.id
              FROM   contractlineitem cli_i
              JOIN   udac u
                ON   cli_i.udac_id = u.id
             WHERE   u.udaccode LIKE '%/F' OR u.udaccode LIKE '%/R'
               AND   cli_i.contract_id = cli.contract_id);
```

Comment: Table structures, sample data, expected output... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TomH Modified question. Is that better?

Comment: You need to put parentheses around your `OR` logic, otherwise the `AND` logic doesn't end up making a difference. Order of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom's comment that your WHERE clause is wrong may be the problem you are chasing.  Plus, using a correlated subquery may be problematic for performance if the optimizer can't figure out a better way to do it.

Here is the better way to do it using an OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT   c.*
  FROM   contract c
  JOIN   contractlineitem cli
    ON   c.id = cli.contract_id
  LEFT   OUTER JOIN udac u
    ON   ( u.id = cli.udac_id 
         AND ( u.udaccode LIKE '%/F' OR u.udaccode LIKE '%/R' ) )
 WHERE   c.entry_timestamp > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
   AND   u.id IS NULL
```

Try that out and see if it does what you want.  The query essentially does what you stated:  It tries to join to udac where the code ends in '/F' or '/R', but then it only accepts the ones where it can't find a match (`u.id IS NULL`).

If the same row is returned multiple times incorrectly, throw a `distinct` on the front.